# Use request to translate file by google.translate.com

Tags: python-requests

I added file translation function for google-trans-new library. All is working fine but the request returns the file I posted. I need help....
[image]

https://gist.github.com/thuanpham582002/a84130c89bc7a91fb200dfd49a07764a

Here is the code: Line 115 - 190

Comment: While providing a GitHub link to your code may be useful, please try to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. While a link may help, somebody should be able to answer your question without clicking on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know where my problem is, in google request there is an element which is 'x-goog-batchexecute-bgr'. value of 'x-goog-batchexecute-bgr' is generated with different files. If incorrect code is generated, it will return the original file. Thank for all!